# Align h3 words to the right bottom

Tags: html, css

i want that the h3 "advertiser" will be aligned to the right under the word "MYNAME"

here is the fiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Uvv9M/2/

the css:

```
#first_section {
   margin:  0 auto;
   margin-top: 200px;
   width: 100%;
   height: 776px;
   font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;

}

#square {
    width:865px;
    height:3px;
    background-color: black;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#first_section_txt {
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:2em;
    word-wrap:word-break;
    font-family:'Source Code Pro', sans-serif;
}

#first_section img {
 margin-left: 25%;
 margin-top: -90px;
 clear: both;

}

.clear_both {
   clear: both;
}
h1 { font-family: 'Source Code Pro', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 111px;
    display: inline;
    color: #4a4949;
     }
h2 { font-family: 'Source Code Pro', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 111px;
    display: inline;
    color: #c0c0c0;
     }
h3 { font-family: 'Source Code Pro', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 25px;
    display: inline;
    color: #a7a7a7;
    float: right;

     }
```

Comment: Do you mean like this? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Uvv9M/3/)

Comment: @Ruddy kinda, notice when you get the screen smaller it goes to the middle and not staying aligned to the right

Comment: This is closer to what you want I guess but when it gets to small it will push it. You can set a `min-width` if that's an option. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Uvv9M/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y35Qa/)

CSS:

```
#first_section {
   margin:  0 auto;
   margin-top: 200px;
   width: 100%;
   height: 776px;
   font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;

}

#first_section_txt {
    width:850px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:2em;
    word-wrap:word-break;
    font-family:'Source Code Pro', sans-serif;
}

#first_section img {
 margin-left: 25%;
 margin-top: -90px;
 clear: both;

}

h1 { font-family: 'Source Code Pro', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 111px;
    display: inline;
    color: #4a4949;
     }
h2 { font-family: 'Source Code Pro', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 111px;
    display: inline;
    color: #c0c0c0;
     }
h3 { font-family: 'Source Code Pro', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-top:0px;
    display: block;
    color: #a7a7a7;
    text-align: right;
    border-top:3px solid #000;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="first_section">
  <div id="first_section_txt">
      <h1>THIS</h1><h2>MYNAME</h2>
      <h3>Graphic Designer and web Advertiser</h3>
  </div>
  <img src="images/me.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: this is good except that i need that the border will be at the same width as the "THIS MYNAME" width

Comment: This is a simple case of changing thee width property, I've updated http://jsfiddle.net/Pt2uh/3/

Comment: Also updated the code above,crucially its width:750px for #first_section_txt

Comment: thanks very much... why there is big gap between "THIS IS..." and the border how can i make the gap smaller?

Comment: Can you give more detail? Not sure which part you mean

Comment: i want less space between the "this myname" and the top border of the h3

Comment: not between the letters, between the "THIS MYNAME" and the top border i want that "THIS MYNAME" will be very close to the border

Comment: The original question has been answered yes? This is another question- that said, you want to change the margin of H3 to a minus value, e.g. -10px;

Comment: No prob, glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/IRuzoPe/2/edit)

[image]

A nice example of **bad SEO**:

```
<h1>THIS</h1><h2>MYNAME</h2>
```

**Should be:**

```
<h1>THIS<span>MYNAME</span></h1>
```

Now instead of doing a line (#square... remove it) you can add a border bottom to `h1`

Than center your inner `#first_section_txt` with `width: 960px`

```
#first_section {
   margin:  0 auto;
   margin-top: 200px;
   width: 100%;
   height: 776px;
   font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
#first_section_txt {
    position:relative;
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    font-family:'Source Code Pro', sans-serif;
}

#first_section img {
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-top: -90px;
    clear: both;
}
h1 {
    text-align:right;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 111px;
    border-bottom:2px solid #4A4949;
    color: #4a4949;
    margin:0px;
    padding-bottom:10px
}
h1 > span{
    color: #c0c0c0;
 }
#first_section_txt > h3 {
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #a7a7a7;
    text-align:right;
}
```

Comment: C.Bulijan Thanks a lot for your explanation! how can i Reduce space between the bottom border and the text?

Comment: @alonblack by simply adding `margin:0;` to `#first_section_txt > h3`

Comment: @alonblack you really tried? cause it works for me: http://jsbin.com/IRuzoPe/4/edit